# Ajax call in cakePhp does not execute the requested php code in controller

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I was handed a project written with cakePhp framework and needed to add some additional function. I tried to follow the existing syntax but somehow couldn't get the new function to work.

The original view file has the following script portion (after the html stuff):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function printorderpage() {
    window.print(); 
}

</script>
```

What I wanted to do is to perform certain database operation (mark a record as locked down so it can no longer be edited) when user prints the page.

Here's what I added to the view file:

```
(function() {
    var beforePrint = function() {
        //console.log('Functionality to run before printing.');
        //alert('before print test');
    };
    var afterPrint = function() {
        //console.log('Functionality to run after printing');
        alert('lock'+<?=$order_id?>);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Workorder/ajaxLockOrder/<?=$order_id?>?debug=false",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: post_data
        }).done(function(e) {
            alert(e.message);
        });

        alert('done?');

    };

    if (window.matchMedia) {
        var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
        mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
            if (mql.matches) {
                beforePrint();
            } else {
                afterPrint();
            }
        });
    }

    window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
    window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
}());
```

Basically the afterPrint function is called whenever user prints the page, and this in turn calls the controller function "ajaxLockOrder" to perform some database operations in the backend. By using the alert box, I could verify that the afterPrint function is executed (the alert pop-up successfully showed the $order_id that needs to be locked, in my test case, order_id is "18", alert box showed "lock18"). But then the ajaxLockOrder was not called?

The controller file is named "workorder_controller.php", and here's the ajaxLockOrder function inside the controller:

```
function ajaxLockOrder($order_id) {
    //once the order is printed, lock the order so it can not be changed
    error_log("executed", 3, "lockerr.log");
    $this->Order->updateActivityStream($order_id, 5); //data operation
}
```

By using the error_log function, I could verify that this function was not executed since the log file was not created.

On the other hand, when I tried to directly type in this function address (http://myurl/Workorder/ajaxLockOrder/18) in browser window, it worked and generated the log file in the backend and updated the database record for order#18. WHY?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'Workorder','action'=>'ajaxLockOrder',$order_id));?>",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: post_data
    }).done(function(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. With this url, it won't even execute the script -- not even the alert box showed up. Something wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I knew it must be something simple. Turns out this particular view page did not have jquery library loaded (probably because it did not need any ajax call before). I added the jquery library and everything worked just fine!

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```